# How come Featured Image isn't showing up in my Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, post-thumbnails

I have thumbnail support added with the following in my functions.php

```
// Add Thumbnail Support
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size( 140, 140, true );
```

And I create the custom post type with

```
// Create Custom Post Type for Work
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'custom_post',
    array(
        'thumbnail',
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Custom' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Custom' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'custom'),
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag')
    )
  );
}
```

However, when I create a new post in the Custom Post Type, the Featured Image meta box does  not show. I have also tried using an array when declaring the custom post type, as follows but that didn't work either

```
// Add Thumbnail Support
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array ('post','work','custom_post'));
set_post_thumbnail_size( 140, 140, true );
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

try the [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters) `supports` parameter:

```
'supports' => array( 'thumbnail' )
```

Comment: Ahhh of course. Either I was staring at it for too long, or I just haven't had enough coffee yet.  Thanks Milo!

Comment: This also remove support of title and editor content, which are enabled by default. I had to use `'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),`.

Comment: Also, remember to actually allow post-thumbnails for your theme like this: `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

Answer (score 8):

Add this parameter into your array:

```
'supports' => array('thumbnail'),
```

Edit: Milo was faster.

Comment: I think this suits my needs better than milo's :D

Answer (score 7):

Try this it works for me.....

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_post_type_support( 'my_product', 'thumbnail' );    
function create_post_type() {
        register_post_type( 'my_product',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true
            )
        );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```