# featured image in custom poste type (backend)

Tags: images, metabox, post-thumbnails

I created a custom post type outside the wordpress loop. I want to integrate the featured image meta box in the backend for this post type.

```
$this->add_meta_box('postimagediv','Beitragsbild', array($this, 'featured_image_meta_box'), 'side');
```

which calls the wordpress core function:

```
protected function add_meta_box($id, $title, $callback, $context = 'normal', $priority = 'default', $callback_args = null ) {
        add_meta_box( 'product_db_' . Kickoff::$action . '_' . $id, $title, $callback, null, $context, $priority, $callback_args);
    }
```

the meta box works, but if i click on add image, it opens an iframe which calls media-upload.php but i want it to look like the normal wordpress mediagalery function like on create posts. This iframe calls the admin-ajax.php.

Does anyone have any idea what i have to change/call in addition to make the iframe work with the default ajax mediagalery?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually adding a metabox, just add `supports` when you register the post type. (Since it is already registered, you may need to `unregister_post_type()` and then re-register it to make this change.)

For details - [How come Featured Image isn't showing up in my Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51897/how-come-featured-image-isnt-showing-up-in-my-custom-post-type#answer-51898)